# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JspException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have the following piece of code:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(address);
dispatcher.forward(req,res);
```

The second line of this code produces the error in the title. Here are my Libraries:

[image]

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.39</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.39</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.39</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
        <version>3.59.81</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
        <version>3.59.81</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
        <version>3.59.81</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JspException
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2651)
    java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1467)
    java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1280)
    java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1141)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:416)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3957)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2212)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1643)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1773)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2452)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$IncludeDirective.accept(Node.java:639)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3503)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:250)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    MT_Servlet.gotoPage(MT_Servlet.java:160)
    MT_TasEntryServlet.doPost(MT_TasEntryServlet.java:1562)
    MT_TasEntryServlet.doGet(MT_TasEntryServlet.java:45)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    MT_Servlet.gotoPage(MT_Servlet.java:160)
    MT_TBLServletController.doPost(MT_TBLServletController.java:217)
    MT_TBLServletController.doGet(MT_TBLServletController.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Does anyone see the issue?

Comment: Post the stacktrace with the respective error message.

Comment: Is there no cause nor anything else that may give us a hint? Also, is this code written directly in your jsp in form of scriptlet or it is in a servlet?

Comment: It is in a servlet. What do you mean "the cause"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javax.servlet.JspException is included in the jsp-api.jar (you can also find containing jars [here](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/servlet/jsp/JspException.html)). For more information have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18208066/2874662).

Answer (score 0):

Add jsp-api.jar into your class path from tomcat lib directory. Right click your project-properties-buildpath-add external jars- go to tomcat lib directory and selece jsp-api.jar.
Then refresh your project. It should remove this exception now.